# Numerical Solution of an SDE in the long time limit. ( Reference?) Stability?

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus, stationary-processes

Consider an SDE (say scalar valued, with some initial value)

\begin{equation*}
    dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dW_t.
\end{equation*}

Fix a time step $\Delta t>0$, and consider its Euler-Maruyama approximation for $j=1,2,\ldots$

\begin{equation*}
    X^{\Delta t}_{j+1}=X^{\Delta t}_j+b(X^{\Delta t}_j)\Delta t + \sigma (X^{\Delta t}_j) \Delta W_j
\end{equation*}

(where $\Delta W_j=W_{j+1}-W_j$). Of course we can send the time step $\Delta t$ to zero and consider the strong and weak error of this numerical method. However I'm looking for a reference which considers the behaviour of the distribution of $X^{\Delta t}_j$ as $j \to \infty$ ( for fixed $\Delta t$ ) - can someone please provide a reference or some insight on this? Of course we will probably have to start by assuming some ergodic properties of the exact process $X_t$.

What is this type of analysis of a numerical solution of an SDE called? Stability?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, the equation for $X_{j}^{\Delta t}$ is just a stochastic difference equation. the "terminal" behaviour of the equation is indeed studied under the concept of stability, covered instochastic control theory literature. Maybe "introduction to stochastic control theory" by K. Astrom can be useful.

Comment: Have you found anything useful? I'm also interested in understanding stability better. See my related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394456/sde-error-and-stability