# SDE error and stability

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I'm interested in understanding the properties of the long term behaviour of a system of stochastic differential equations. For example, given a coupled system
\begin{align}
d x&=f(x,y)dt+\phi(x,y)dW_1\\
d y&=g(x,y)dt+\sigma(x,y)dW_2
\end{align}
where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are Wiener processes, what can be said about the long term behaviour of the errors (or stability)
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to\infty}|x(t+\Delta t)-x(t)|\\
\lim_{t\to\infty}|y(t+\Delta t)-y(t)|
\end{align}
I am not quite sure where to start, so I'd be glad to have some suggestions.

**My approach:** Assume $(x^*,y^*)$ represents the steady state solution of the deterministic system. In the mean square, $\Delta W= \Delta t^\frac12\xi$, where $\xi$ represents white noise. For large $t$ and without loss of generality, we take the infinitesimal difference of $x$
\begin{align*}
x(t+\Delta t)-x(t)&=f(x^*+\delta x,y^*+\delta y)\Delta t+\phi(x^*+\delta x,y^*+\delta y)\Delta t^\frac12\xi_1
\end{align*}
First-order Taylor expanding around $(\delta x,\delta y)$ leads to the vanishing of the terms involving $f$ and thus
\begin{align*}
x(t+\Delta t)-x(t)&=\phi(x^*,y^*)\Delta t^\frac12\xi_1+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\phi(x^*,y^*)\delta x\Delta t^\frac12\xi_1+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\phi(x^*,y^*)\delta y\Delta t^\frac12\xi_1
\end{align*}
excluding higher order terms. Would it be possible to simplify or estimate this further? My ultimate goal is to get an upper bound for the error for large $t$.

Any way of justifying, for example, taking the large $t$ estimate
$$
\frac{x(t+\Delta t)-x(t)}{\Delta t^\frac12}\approx \phi(x^*,y^*)\xi_1
$$

Comment: Depends how big $\Delta t$ is relative to the coefficients. The limits almost never exist regardless, though.

Comment: @Ian Is it possible to estimate an upper bound for large $t$?

Comment: If there's a local attractor in the deterministic dynamics and the realization is actually pulled near it, potentially. Otherwise I doubt it.

Comment: You need more information on the SDE to say something meaningful about these quantities. For instance, you can take X_t to be BM so that these quantities converge only in distribution; X could also be a martingale that converges almost surely to a constant, so that these differences may vanish in the limit.

Comment: @Ian I understand. Please take a look at my approach, under a strong assumption on the system. Let me know what you think and whether it is possible to estimate something with this.

Comment: @JoseAvilez I see. Please take a look at the edited question and let me know what you think.

Comment: In the presence of an asymptotically stable equilibrium of the deterministic dynamics, Freidlin-Wentzell theory can be used. It doesn't actually say that you stay near the asymptotically stable equilibrium forever upon starting there, however. You always move far away eventually, if the noise coefficient matrix is everywhere nonsingular.

Comment: @Ian could you point me in which chapter in their book is this discussed?

Comment: Most of the book is about this general type of thing, but the main centerpiece of the case I brought up is Chapter 4. It's a bit hard to understand without the background from at least Chapter 2, though.

Answer (score 1):

The book ["Stochastic Stability of Differential Equations"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-23280-0) also covers the case of long-term behaviour for systems of SDEs. If you have some specific coefficients, we can try to build the corresponding Lyapunov funciton.